# How to open the camera within the size?

Tags: camera, windows-phone-7.1

I want to open the camera action like below pictures. just like camera open within some area only for focusing particular area of the image.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**Normal Camera View**

[image]

**My Expectation**

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do? What's the problem you've got?

Comment: I want reduce the camera focusing area...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `CameraCaptureTask`, you will have to deal with its possibilities. It uses the built-in camera app of the phone, and available setting are the ones in that app.

If you prefer a customized photo taking app, you should use the `PhotoCamera` class:

[PhotoCamera Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.photocamera%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

You will find some guidance here:

[How to create a base camera app for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)